# Is the highlight for interesting questions in SF too light?

Tags: feature-request

Is the highlight for interesting questions in SF too light?

I think it is.  I barely noticed that I already have interesting tags until I shifted my view from my monitor.

Increasing the contrast of the interesting question would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Preface: I'm color blind and rarely use ServerFault.

Yes, yes it is way too light. Please darken it for us folks who have trouble comparing colors.

Comment: Perhaps I'm color blind as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks and feels fine.

It's on that shade just before being too dark and way too light to notice. But right now, it's a nice kind of pancake batter hue to it.

But that's only from a perspective on a non-colour blind user. If you are, then [as Eric points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20804/is-the-highlight-for-interesting-questions-in-sf-too-light/21562#21562), it's waaaaaaaaaaaaay too light to differentiate.