# Answered questions styling

Tags: feature-request, answers

Could answered questions be restyled with a solid colour fill like the other sites please? It is hard to tell from a glance which questions have a marked answered. thanks.

Comment: I think something like this has been asked before; the fact that http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/208/is-the-highlight-for-interesting-questions-in-sf-too-light is still open suggests this isn't going to be fixed -- unfortunately, since I find the current colour differentiation in answered/accepted to be far too subtle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SF's color scheme *is* subtle. I've posted answers about that before, though I'm having trouble identifying those questions.

[image]<- Server Fault [image]<- Security

To the colorblind the top two are nigh indistinguishable (there is an android app that provides colorblind simulation for those with good color vision), with very slight contrast differences. To me the bottom two have good contrast, so long as I'm using a good monitor.

Because I spend a *lot* of time here (moderation doesn't apply to moderators it seems) I have no trouble seeing the contrast from the bottom two at a glance. Even though I can't hunt up some of my older screen-caps, it does seem to me that this is better than what we started with. Even so, it still isn't the "accepted-is-filled" convention that many other sites follow.

[image: IT-Security] IT Security

That one is also subtle, but the nice minty green fill does provide a different visual cue than we have on SF. Is this better? Maybe. DBA, Unix, and Webmasters all follow a similar minty-green scheme.

SF's scheme predates the rest of StackExchange, so we have that whole 'legacy' thing going for us. The Red/Green thing is an issue that I believe needs fixing. An in-fill color would fix that, in my opinion.

Comment: anything that adds tonal contrast is definitely gonna be better.

Comment: I would also prefer a fill in color, the 'answer selected' is pretty hard to pick out.